# Widget page is missing from menu and default widgets are not showing

Tags: widgets, admin-menu

***Necessary background information: I'm working on a website which were first developped by an other web agency. So I don't have all of the history of the project.***

I have an issue with a Wordpress installation: the Widgets page isn't showing in the administration menu under Appearance. If I access the page directly by typing URL (`wp-admin/widgets.php`) the page is showing, but I can only see a WPML widget (language selector) and a custom sidebar I've made for my theme. All the defaults WP widgets are missing.

[image: Screen of the Widgets page]

If I **disable all the plugins** and **switch to the twentyfifteen theme** the Widgets link is not showing either, and I can't even access to the `wp-admin/widgets.php` page - an error is showing saying that the theme isn't ready for widgets. Though twentyfifteen is supposed to register a sidebar (see `twentyfifteen_widgets_init` in *functions.php*).

So **using the twentyfifteen theme with no plugins enabled** I tried the following:

- Replace all the `wp-content` and `wp-includes` files with original one, in case of they would have been altered by the other developpers.
- Replace the `twentyfifteen` theme with the original one, in case of the same reason as above.
- Enabled the `WP_DEBUG` mode to see if any error shows up.

But none of this help. What I can only see is that there is something in the database that is wrong. I checked the widgets options in `wp_options` table but it seems ok:

```
> select * from wp_options where option_name like '%widget%';
+-----------+------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
| option_id | option_name            | option_value                                                                                                           | autoload |
+-----------+------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
|        82 | widget_categories      | a:2:{i:2;a:4:{s:5:"title";s:0:"";s:5:"count";i:0;s:12:"hierarchical";i:0;s:8:"dropdown";i:0;}s:12:"_multiwidget";i:1;} | yes      |
|        83 | widget_text            | a:0:{}                                                                                                                 | yes      |
|        84 | widget_rss             | a:0:{}                                                                                                                 | yes      |
|        93 | widget_search          | a:2:{i:2;a:1:{s:5:"title";s:0:"";}s:12:"_multiwidget";i:1;}                                                            | yes      |
|        94 | widget_recent-posts    | a:2:{i:2;a:2:{s:5:"title";s:0:"";s:6:"number";i:5;}s:12:"_multiwidget";i:1;}                                           | yes      |
|        95 | widget_recent-comments | a:2:{i:2;a:2:{s:5:"title";s:0:"";s:6:"number";i:5;}s:12:"_multiwidget";i:1;}                                           | yes      |
|        96 | widget_archives        | a:2:{i:2;a:3:{s:5:"title";s:0:"";s:5:"count";i:0;s:8:"dropdown";i:0;}s:12:"_multiwidget";i:1;}                         | yes      |
|        97 | widget_meta            | a:2:{i:2;a:1:{s:5:"title";s:0:"";}s:12:"_multiwidget";i:1;}                                                            | yes      |
|        98 | sidebars_widgets       | a:2:{s:19:"wp_inactive_widgets";a:0:{}s:13:"array_version";i:3;}                                                       | yes      |
+-----------+------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
```

I checked the global `$wp_registered_widgets` content, and as expected it only contain the WPML widget (when enabled).

That's all I could came up with. Anyone have a tip on this on what could be checked further?

Comment: Corrupted WP core possibly? You could try reinstalling it.

Comment: Is everything alright with your `functions.php` file? Have you tried [this][1]?


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17673264/widgets-menu-not-appear-under-appearance-on-wordpress-dashboard

Comment: @marquito It's been long time I do not work on this project anymore. As I said the problem occcured even when I switched back to twentyfifteen so it's not related to the theme functions.php. And this link is related to someone developping a new theme and who don't know how to register a sidebar. This is not related to this issue where the DB were corrupted (a fresh installation of WP with the old DB produced the same outcome). For the record, the company I worked with finished by giving up this project and started a new website from scratch.